# I have a list of names as <li>, clicking on the name should save it to local storage... code attached

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this names list, if they click on a name it should save to local storage and displayed in a  div.

```
<ul class="namelist">
<li>Liam</li> 
<li>Noah</li> 
<li>William</li> 
<li>James</li> 
<li>Oliver</li> 
<li>Benjamin</li> 
<li>Elijah</li> 
<li>Lucas</li> 
</ul>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$( 'ul.namelist li' ).on( "click", function() {   
   var name = ( $( this ).text() );  
   var last = "";
   var c = sessionStorage.setItem(name,last);  
   });
})

function doFirst(){
display();
}

function display (){
var display_data = document.getElementById('display_data');
display_data.innerHTML="";
for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++){
var a = sessionStorage.key(i);
var b = sessionStorage.getItem(a);
display_data.innerHTML += a+""+b+"<br>";
}
}

function clear(){
sessionStorage.clear();
location.reload();
}

window.addEventListener("load",doFirst,false);
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form>
<section id="box">
<a href="javascript:clear()">Clear Items</a>
</section>
<section id="display_data" style="border: 2px solid #000; width: 250px;">

</section>

<ul class="namelist">
<li>Liam</li> 
<li>Noah</li> 
<li>William</li> 
<li>James</li> 
<li>Oliver</li> 
<li>Benjamin</li> 
<li>Elijah</li> 
<li>Lucas</li> 
</ul>
</form>
```

Please help me modify the code to capture a click on `<li>` and store the same. You can use JQuery too.

Thanks, please help, I am learning Javascript.

Comment: this is a code request not a question

Comment: new here, is there a separate section for code request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try

**Html**

```
<ul class="namelist">
<li>Liam</li> 
<li>Noah</li> 
<li>William</li> 
<li>James</li> 
<li>Oliver</li> 
<li>Benjamin</li> 
<li>Elijah</li> 
<li>Lucas</li> 
</ul>
<div id="divShow">
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$('.namelist li').click(e=>{    
    localStorage.setItem($(e.currentTarget).text(), $(e.currentTarget).text());
    $('#divShow').append('<p>'+$(e.currentTarget).text()+'</p>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Amit, it works with so much less code. Great help. But on page refresh the data is lost.

Comment: The requirement is to display the selected names in another page or during another visit.

Comment: try this      
(()=>{
if(sessionStorage.getItem('myList')!=undefined){

$('#divShow').html(sessionStorage.getItem('myList'));

}})()

$('.namelist li').click(e=>{    

 sessionStorage.setItem('myList', sessionStorage.getItem('myList')!=undefined?sessionStorage.getItem('myList')+'<br/>' + $(e.currentTarget).text():$(e.currentTarget).text());
 console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('myList'));
 $('#divShow').html(sessionStorage.getItem('myList')); 
});